# Deploying Laravel "schedule:run" vs "queue:work"

Tags: laravel, continuous-deployment

When we have a worker instance, we can run this command:

```sh
php artisan queue:work --queue=default --daemon --tries=5
```

Rigth? Then, if we have already ran the previous command, is it neccessary add `schedule:run` to the cron job?

```sh
php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Both commands are required? Or just one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two commands are totally different and do two completely different things.
`artisan queue:work` starts a queue worker for your asynchronous jobs and event listeners to run in the background when dispatched.
`artisan schedule:run` executes the commands defined in your `Console\Kernel` `schedule` function at the specified time (that's what CRON means)

**Examples**

1- `queue:work`

Given a Job Class like this

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class LogStuff implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        info('stuff');
    }
}
```

And a route that dispatches the job like this
`routes/web.php`

```
use App\Jobs\LogStuff;

Route::get('/', function () {
    dispatch(new LogStuff());
    return view('welcome');
});
```

And `QUEUE_CONNECTION` in the `.env` like this

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
```

> Nothing is logged until the php artisan queue:work command is ran

[image: Queue Worker in Action]

The Job is processed twice because the first dispatch without the queue worker running just adds it to the queue (in redis for example)

2- Scheduled commands

Given a scheduled command defined in `App\Console\Kernel` like this

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $date = now()->format('Y-m-d');
   $logfileFullpath = storage_path("logs/laravel-{$date}.log");
   $schedule->command('inspire')
            ->everyMinute()
            ->sendOutputTo($logfileFullpath);
}
```

> Nothing is outputted to the console until php artisan schedule:run is executed

1 minute later
[image: Scheduled task ran]

Comment: thanks! then, the conclusion is **Both commands are required**

Comment: No! it depends on whether you have **both** asynchrounous jobs and scheduled commands

Comment: yeap! I have listeners whith shouldQueue and $schedule->command() on Kernel. Then, I required both commands. If I wrong, please tell me. Thanks again.

Comment: Listeners implementing the `shouldQueue` interface requires a queue worker not a task scheduler